# How to use applyBindings for same element without using ko.cleanNode method

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, knockout-3.0

I'm creating simple application in **KnockoutJS**, here i need more input elements to update in a single button click. I have used ***ko.applyBindings(viewModel)***, but it throws below error.

> Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.
>       at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (VM88 knockout-debug.js:3287)

I have found one solution, if i use *ko.cleanNode(node)* it solves my problem. But i don't want this because, i have many input elements. So obviously i need to clean each node for every button click. Any other solution in generic to use applyBindings for same element or else, i need to change core?

```js
applybind = function() {
  viewModel = {
    nValue: ko.observable(10)
  }
  //ko.cleanNode(document.getElementById("txt")); // Don't want this.
  ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}

ko.applyBindings({
  nValue: ko.observable(100)
}); //initial load.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" data-bind="value: nValue" />
<input type="button" value="update value" onclick="applybind()" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general `ko.applyBinding` method should be called only once. After that you can simply change observable values and changes will immediately be reflected in the UI.
I've changed your snipped accordingly.

```js
viewModel = {
  nValue: ko.observable(100)
}

applybind = function() {
  viewModel.nValue(10);
}

ko.applyBindings(viewModel); //initial load.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txt" data-bind="value: nValue" />
<input type="button" value="update value" onclick="applybind()" />
```